# Redis query with Latest date and unique id

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

We are using Redis connection with JedisConnectionFactory and using CrudRepository for querying data

```
@Component
@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

  @Bean
  public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisProperties redisProperties) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory(redisProperties));
    return template;
  }

  private JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(RedisProperties redisProperties) {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration =
        new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisProperties.getHost(), redisProperties.getPort());
    return new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
  }
}
```

My Redis Object

```
@RedisHash("Resource")
public class ResourceDto {
    @Id private String resourceId;
    @Indexed private Date lastUpdatedDate;
    private String resource;
}
```

I want to fetch all unique ResourceDto by resourceId with Latest lastUpdatedDate. 
I have tried with few things
Using findByDistinctResourceId() but it gives error
Is there any alternative?
Dont know how to query for this kind of result using RedisTemplate

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx =
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    RedisTemplate redisTemplate=ctx.getBean(RedisTemplate.class);
    RedisScript redisScript=new RedisScript() {
      @Override
      public String getSha1() {
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      public Class getResultType() {
        return ResourceDto.class;
      }

      @Override
      public String getScriptAsString() {
        return "SORT Resource BY nosort";
      }
    };
    redisTemplate.execute(redisScript,null,null);

  }
```

RedisTemplate is configured properly but dont know how to query for all unique ResourceDto by resourceId with Latest lastUpdatedDate